# Android Multiple Toasts

Tags: android

I wanted multiple toasts to be present in a single onClick function which i have defined in xml.

```
public void confirm(View v) {
    Name = text1.getText().toString();
    age = text2.getText().toString();
    phonenumber = text3.getText().toString();
    gender="";

    if(r1.isChecked())
        gender="MALE";
    else if(r2.isChecked())
        gender="FEMALE";
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select Gender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (Name.length()==0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name Is A Mandatory Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(age.length()>3 || age.length()==0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Correct Age",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(age.length()>0 && Name.length()>0 && gender.length()>0 && phonenumber.length()>0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

This doesnt seems to be working.Only Gender Works .Others dont work at all.

Comment: Are you sure the other if conditions are"true" ?

Comment: Advice: Don't use if statements without braces. It's not only hard to read but also very error prone.

Comment: You probably don't want to stack Toasts like this. You should either have a dialog alert the user of the condition issues or place the entire message in a single condensed Toast. Other than that, you sure your conditionals are met?

Answer (score 0):

This will catch whichever error comes first. I'd suggest ordering them in order of input field in your UI.

```
if(!r1.isChecked && !r2.isChecked)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select Gender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else if (Name.length()==0)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name Is A Mandatory Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else if(age.length()>3 || age.length()==0)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Correct Age",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else if(age.length()>0 && Name.length()>0 && gender.length()>0 && phonenumber.length()>0)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else if(r1.isChecked()) 
    gender="MALE";
else if(r2.isChecked())
    gender="FEMALE";
```

It is not an ideal way to validate user input. It's not a good idea to have mutliple toasts showing up one after the other. In a website if a user misses several fields you can have a custom notification saying, please input all fields, or just put up the notification for the first field missed and then when that is done, the next missing field notification will show up.

Answer (score -1):

Use if (Name.trim().equals("")) instead of if (Name.length==0)

```
public void confirm(View v) {
    Name = text1.getText().toString();
    age = text2.getText().toString();
    phonenumber = text3.getText().toString();
    gender="";

    if(r1.isChecked())
        gender="MALE";
    else if(r2.isChecked())
        gender="FEMALE";
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select Gender",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    **if (Name.trim().equals(""))**
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name Is A Mandatory Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    **if(age.length()>3 || age.trim().equals(""))**
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Correct Age",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(age.length()>0 && Name.length()>0 && gender.length()>0 && phonenumber.length()>0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please, at least add some explanation to your answer.